# Bob Marley music or Bob Marley's music

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Which of these sentences would you say? I think they're both idiomatic. What's the difference between them?

I listen to Bob Marley music.

or

I listen to Bob Marley's music.

Comment: “I listen to the Specials and Bob Marley” (?) You don't need to specify what (music) you are listening to if the artist is world-renowned, e.g. *I nearly always listen to Frank Sinatra in the car.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is acceptable. The meaning is very slightly different, primarily a question of emphasis. The difference is very slight.

- I listen to Bob Marley music.

This refers to the music made by Bob Marley as a category. That is, the collection of music made by Bob Marley is what I listen to.

It could, potentially though not necessarily, include music that was very similar to such music (same style, etc.) but not *actually* made by Bob Marley. Though I cannot offer anything in that particular category.  If you intended such you would make it clear with additional context.

It might be more likely to have such a meaning if it was some other person. "Shakespeare music" might indicate music written by Shakespeare, or it might indicate music written in that era or in the style of that era.

- I listen to Bob Marley's music.

This is indicating the music that *belongs* to Bob Marley. That is, it is somewhat more tightly focussing on music that was produced (written, played, etc.) by Bob Marley. It is less likely to refer to music of the same general type or style.

Thumbs up for using Bob Marley as the example. There are a few musical individuals whose name has a certain delightful possibility for word play. George Thorogood is often referred to as "George Thoroughly Good" for example. And Bob Marley is sometimes referred to as "Marley Bob" with some winking-and-nodding as to what "Marley" means as an adjective.